# Checkbox check jquery is not working after loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, contact-form-7

This is the code I am using right now, for cf7 wordpress, but when I load the page it is checking it but after fully load of page it is going to uncheck again.
I just want to get the checkbox checked by default.
Here is the code,

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
 $('#cus_checkbox').find('input').prop( 'checked', true );
 });
```

Any help on this?

Comment: Issue could be with the selector, please add the relevant HTML.

Comment: As you are using contactform7 you should also look into ways of setting a default value with this plug-in. Maybe something like this works: `[checkbox* cus_checkbox  default:on "label text"]` ?

Comment: @CarstenMassmann not working with default:on, Already tried

Comment: Another guess: `default:1`?

Comment: @CarstenMassmann ohh yeah, that's working. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to have a "registered" answer here I repeat my comment again as an answer:

In order to get the contactform 7 checkbox checked by default you should specify it when you define the cf7 element by adding `default:1`:

```
 [checkbox* cus_checkbox  default:1 "some label text"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, my reputation is not enough for comment so I am writing as an answer

try by doing this

```
<input type="checkbox" id="cus_checkbox" checked="true" />
```